# Тюркский алфавит в аргументе file_get_contents

Tags: php, unicode, file-get-contents, urlencode

Есть сайт на азербайджанском языке, есть на нём скрипт subcat.php который должен получить содержимое файла Güləş.txt.

```
$sbct = 'Güləş.txt';
```

В  htaccess, в скрипте и в текстовом файле стоит UTF-8 без BOM. Вот такие способы ничего не дают:

```
 $text = file_get_contents($sbct);
$text = file_get_contents(urlencode($sbct));
```

В обоих случая эхо даёт пустой результат. Желательно получить содержимое именно из файла, не прибегая к SQL

Answer (score 0):

Переведите название файла в Unicode. Например так:

```
var_dump(mb_chr(0x010F));
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, но увы у меня и htaccess, и файлы и строка url($sbct) и так Юникод, на всякий случай проверил - mb_detect_encoding($sbct) возвращает UTF-8.  А  mb_chr() вообще не работает, может версия PHP - 5.6.19 - не подходит. Вообще, весь сайт спокойно отрабатывает и русские и азербайджанские тексты, весь кроме файлгетконтентс